# All USB Devices randomly disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: windows-10, usb

For seemingly no reason, all of my usb devices disconnect and reconnect. I dont know why it happens, but when I'm playing games suddenly all devices, including my headset and mouse disconnect and after a few seconds they reconnect. It can range from something like 2 seconds up to 20 seconds Somehow it doesn't affect my Keyboard but its quite annoying. Rebooting doesnt change anything and I'm using windows 10

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the issue? First thing you should do is reboot, then check if the issue persists with only one device connected. Change the connected device, until you've found the one where the problem happens.

Comment: I've got this problem for quite some time now. I've tried rebooting my pc but it doesn't do anything. But it all started when i got my water cooling. I hear the disconnecting sound a few times and the rgb coler of the AIO resets. And sometimes my mouse, microphone and my headset disconnect all at once

Comment: @mashuptwice And consider that the problem might be a cable rather than a device.

Comment: I had this problem in the past and it was due to one of the USB devices drawing more power while gaming. Basically I could never have a disc in a USB DVD drive while gaming or I would have trouble. Most likely it is a power supply issue.

Comment: @ch0nky.Chungus You should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1752200/edit) your question and include that.

Comment: @Mokubai yes, deifintely my guess too. I have the same problem and I can make it go away if I lower the amount of USB devices. I am planning to upgrade my PSU at some time, but when I upgraded one of my USB hubs to a powered one, the problem was also reduced quite a bit.

Comment: I dont think the psu is the problem... I got a ROG Strix 750W power supply. I do have a ryzen 7 3700X and a rtx 3080, but Im pretty sure the powersupply should be able to handle this. And all of the cables are intact. I've got this problem with two different mouses, headsets and keyboards.

Comment: @ch0nky.Chungus the problem is that in most systems the vast majority of that 750W is going straight into the 12V rails for the CPU and GPU power power regulators to convert down to various voltages right at the point of needing them. The 5V out of the PSU might be slightly weak, or there could be USB power regulators or something else that is a bit weedy on your motherboard.

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS and drivers?  Either your devices are not getting the power they need or your motherboard is bad.  It might be possible you connected the USB cable from your water cooler to your motherboard backwards.

Comment: soo. its been some time since i've buildt this thing, so im not quite sure how to see if the cable's backwards. But i've lowered the amount of usb devices and since then it doesnt happen as often as before. It still happens sometimes but it's gotten rarer...